# How to get a kendogrid for a kendotreeview selection by using html helper

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

I am new to this kendo ui framework and telerik docs I could not find the solution which I am seeking. Right now I created a treeview by using html helper as shown below, my requirement is if I select any of a node I have to get a grid on right side (or anywhere downside or) how to get that, the code which i did right now is shown below

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
      .Name("treeview") //The name of the treeview is mandatory. It specifies the "id" attribute of the widget.
      .Items(items =>
      {
          items.Add().Text("SystemModelling"); //Add item with text "Item1")
          items.Add().Text("SystemConfiguration") //Add item with text "Item2")
              .Items(it => it.Add().Text("Root"));

          items.Add().Text("Domains"); //Add item with text "Item1")
          items.Add().Text("Roles"); //Add item with text "Item2")
          items.Add().Text("Users"); //Add item with text "Item1")

      })
      .Events(ev=>ev.Select("treeview_select"))
)

<script>
    $(function () {
        // Notice that the Name() of the treeview is used to get its client-side instance
        var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
    });
</script>
```

What coding I have to do in `treeview_select` event?

**EDIT**

ONe simple doubt which is best way to work in kendo ui, whether to use Html helper or kendo javascript.IF helper is a wrapper then what is the difference between helper and javascript

Comment: Launch a partial view with the Kendo Grid when a tree view item is selected

Comment: ONe simple doubt which is best way to work in kendo ui, whether to use Html helper or kendo javascript.IF helper is a wrapper then what is the difference between helper and javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need create grid in PartialView and then just read id when you select a node in treeView:

1. In the right side of the treeView (`Index.cshtml`) you must creating container to fit your grid eg.:

   ```
   <div id="GridContainer"></div>
   ```
2. In PartialView, name it eg. `Grid.cshtml` you're creating grid using Html.Helper like in [this kendoGrid demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/index).
3. In Controller you're declaring action to read this PartialView like that:

   ```
   public partial class GridController : Controller 
   {
       [HttpPost]
           public PartialViewResult Grid()
           {
               return PartialView();
           }
   }
   ```
4. In Index.html you can create hidden in your `Index.html` to make sure that your PartialView URL is correct:

   ```
   @Html.Hidden("GridURL", Url.Action("Grid", "Grid"))
   ```
5. You are creating JavaScript function to read this grid on treeView select using ajax():

   ```
   <script>
       function treeview_select(e){
           $.ajax({
               url: $("#GridURL").val(),
               type: "POST",
               success: function (result) {
                   $("#GridContainer").html(result);
               }
           });
       }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: problem now i am having is, i need grid also in html helper way, i am binding it like that .Here the grid is generating based on javascript which i dont want

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question. I totally updated my answer.

Comment: ONe simple doubt which is best way to work in kendo ui, whether to use Html helper or kendo javascript.IF helper is a wrapper then what is the difference between helper and javascript

Comment: This is actally very good question. Html helper just generate javascript code and paste it to view. It is convenient if you familiar with C# more than JS. The second advantage is a little bit better IntelliSense for C#. Now disadvantages: C# do not have all functions what JavaScript wrapper have. You can't avoid JS in events handling - you have to write it in JavaScript. And Kendo with C# are more expensive (699$ JS/999$ MVC last time I checked).